# How to represent functions in REST APIs which are not actually resources?

Tags: rest

When defining a REST API nouns usually represent resources on which the HTTP verbs can be applied.

For example: `GET /user/profile/{id}` or `POST /user/profile`.

But not all functions can be represented by typical resources. For example, the combination of a registration key and a secret need to be validated. How would I represent that method in a REST API?

Comment: I had to implement a sort of REST API route for validation with a PIN which is similar in your case. I implemented a `POST` route to prevent sending the PIN data in the URL and then ( with proper authentication of the user and perhaps a timeout between requests ) send back HTTP status codes either `200` as success or `400` as failure, adding to timeout.

Comment: @zatyh How did you name that non-resource resource?

Comment: similar to your answer from Ioan, the route was named `/settings/validate` because the PIN was part of a client's settings and the only thing in settings to be validated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A concrete answer to your question would be:

```
POST to /RegistrationValidation
Request body:
{
    "key": "..."
    "secret": "..."
}
```

And you respond with a 200 OK if the data the server received is valid or some other status code if not.

**The point here is that:**

- your API resources shouldn't be mapped one to one to your domain model. You shouldn't always stick to a CRUD style when designing your API.
- you are free to design your API in a **fine grained**, **coarse grained** style or **mix them** if in the end it is friendly for the consuming client. Any verb can be 'nounified' and you end up with a new Resource. You can have a resource which is modifying multiple underlying domain models to solve a specific business need and this is completely fine. But stay consistent with your decisions and don't forget that freedom implies responsibility. You have an infinite URI space but make sure you don't end up with a lot of resources just because you can.

While I was writing this answer I recalled where I saw all these recommendations and I am really happy this 2014 article is still up, I really recommend it:
https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/rest-api-design-resource-modeling

Answer (score 1):

> How to represent functions in REST APIs which are not actually resources?

Pretty much anything you can think to ask about is a resource.  From [Fielding's thesis](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1):

> The key abstraction of information in REST is a resource. Any information that can be named can be a resource: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on. In other words, any concept that might be the target of an author's hypertext reference must fit within the definition of a resource. A resource is a conceptual mapping to a set of entities, not the entity that corresponds to the mapping at any particular point in time.

The target-uri is just an identifier; it can really be anything you want.  For example

```
/AAFE4035-C6E4-4897-B174-5FD0105DFF7A
```

is a perfectly fine identifier for a resource.

A way of thinking about it: resource identifiers are a lot like variable names.  The machines don't care what spelling you use.  The spelling conventions are there for the human beings.

Sometimes this heuristic helps: how would you do it with a web site?  The user would start with some bookmarked URI, and then follow links and submit forms until the work was done.  What identifiers would you use in that case?